# 404 not found (port 443) wordpress

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I cannot access my wordpress site www.artintheciy.in Actually i tried to changes the URL from the settings from hhtp to https by mistake and now it shows this error (i do not have  any SSL certificate) :

404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:

www.artinthecity.in/wp-admin/ (port 443)
Please forward this error screen to www.artinthecity.in's WebMaster.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem?
 I just wanna get rid of this error asap. I don't want to setup any SSL certificate. Thanks

Comment: You tried change it back to http?

Comment: @TurtleTread I cannot login to wordpress. It does not allow me to get through that error page

Comment: check your wp_config.php file for wp_siteurl and wp_home constants to see if they have http prefix. There's also database search and replace scripts online to help you replace all field values that contain your https site url with http, or you can try run an update in probably the wp_options table.

Comment: @TurtleTread I don't know how but now i have installed wordpress from beginning. I just made a change in wp_config.php file. It was somewhere wpff_ and I changed it to wp_ . Then it just installed new wordpress. I am beginner in this coding game. But thanks anyway :)